# Import data from a .csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

How this application works:
The user inputs a Store number.
Upon hitting GO, it will pull Address/City/State/Zip from a .csv file

Example of the .css file:

*In Excel*

```
StoreNumber Address                           City          State   ZipCode
295         4425 14TH ST W                    BRADENTON     FL      34207
296         4942 S TAMIAMI TRL                SARASOTA      FL      34231
297         10261 RIVER MARSH DR UNIT 143     JACKSONVILLE  FL      32246
```

*In notepad*

```
StoreNumber,Address,City,State,ZipCode,Telephone
295,4425 14TH ST W,BRADENTON,FL,34207,
296,4942 S TAMIAMI TRL,SARASOTA,FL,34231,
297,10261 RIVER MARSH DR UNIT 143,JACKSONVILLE,FL,32246,
```

I have tried this before, but just got frustrated.
I would like to reopen this task, this time with help!

I think I have included all the required information.
Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: I looked at that post already. I am unsure how to put each item into a diffrent text box. Exaple: Address ill go into addresstextbox and City will go into citytextbox

Comment: For this kind of layout a `DataGridView` would be better.

Comment: @OneFineDay That would be easier, but I already have the program fully built to support the textboxs. With them it formats and exports them to an email. Normally I would just recode it, but it has to be a specific format, and as far as I am aware DataGridView would just display all together.

Comment: YEah in columns and rows.

Comment: Do you have rows and columns of textboxes for the data?

Comment: It is easy enough to parse the fields from a selected row of the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Here is a picture to help me explain. So the information on the right is the output. It has to be in the format, and the information on the left is where it pulls the information. http://imgur.com/7xueTps ---- sorry if I am making this confusing :(

Comment: Sure, but your file has more than one line so how do you plan on accounting for that? Which is several groups of data.

Comment: The main .csv file has 1200+ lines in it. So user inputs (example) 1234, and it pulls just the address/zip/ect for that store. - Currently, users have to enter it all in manually, it works, I just want it more userfriendly.

Comment: To bad this isn't database. Simple query for 1 record.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make it easier? I can change the type of file it reads, or even include it in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your question is ask about how to read a CSV file?
Below is a sample code how to read a CSV file (C#) Hopefully it help you^^

```
private const string COMMENTSTRING = "@#@#";//Comment string

        /// <summary>
        /// Use to import CSV item Info
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="FileLocation">Import From</param>
        /// <returns>CSVItemInfo Object</returns>
        public System.Collections.ArrayList Import(string FileLocation)
        {
            ArrayList arrData = new ArrayList();;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            try
            {
                //Read all line
                while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
                {
                    string val = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (val.Trim().Contains(COMMENTSTRING)) //Skip read comment
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    string[] retVal = val.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    string StoreNumber = retVal[0];
                    string Address = retVal[1];
                    //ETC.......

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }


            return arrData;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My questions I guess would be, how to get the store user is searching for, and pull the data all into separate textboxs

Comment: it would be the same, you can just add if condition to search the store number that user enter and return the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's my shot at it.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("your file path")
  Dim data = sr.ReadToEnd.Split(Environment.NewLine).
                FirstOrDefault(Function(line) line.Split(","c)(0) = "1234")
  'data now contains the comma separated data
  If Not data Is Nothing
     'can be nothing due to the `FirstOrDefualt` function
  End If
End Using
```